# Using text document of whitespace containing filenames to batchcopy between directories in Terminal

Tags: terminal, script, zsh

I am using terminal in MacOS Ventura. I want to have a textfile of files which I will copy using the terminal. This won't work when spaces are in the filenames.

```
A=~/Documents/test1
B=~/Documents/test2

while IFS= read -r file; do
cp "${A}/${file}" "${B}"
done < ~/Documents/testme.txt
```

Here is the example text file.

```
# contents of ~/Documents/testme.txt
the first file.pdf
the second file.pdf
the third file.pdf
```

After running the code above I get:

```
cp: /Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the second file.pdf: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the third file.pdf: No such file or directory
```

I assume this is because of the whitespaces in the filename, but let's assume I want to use a textfile with non-escaped whitespace files separated only with a line break.

How is this done?

Even when I attempt to escape the use quotes, the following errors occur.

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
cp "\"${A}/${file}"\" "\"${B}/${file}"\"
done < ~/Documents/testme.txt
cp: "/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf": No such file or directory
cp: "/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the second file.pdf": No such file or directory
cp: "/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the third file.pdf": No such file or directory
```

Yet no trouble copy-pasting that same line!

`cp "/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf" ./test2` Works!

EDIT, zsh version: `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`.

Comment: The first attempt should work, the second for sure doesn't (because the quoting results in `"` being part of the filename). Did you check whether the files to be copied actually are in `test1`? How was `testme.txt` created and the filename entered? If you create (for testing) a file without whitespace in `test1` and add its name to `testme.txt`, does it work for that file?

Comment: "How was testme.txt created and the filename entered? " I typed the filenames into the text file (without quotes, ensuring there was \n separating each filename, then used `touch` to make those files

Comment: If you add a file name/file without whitespace, does it work?

Comment: @nohillside yes. it also works for the solution offered below. @ JLpeyret makes the text file using echo, whereas I typed it in textview. Is it possible Mac has a different spacebar space used in echo and textedit?

Comment: There is no difference between echo and textedit on this. My assumption still is that you misstyped something, or had CRLF lineendings or something like that.

Comment: re CRLF lineendings, can you elaborate on this? Also is there a difference between UTF-8 and 16? I copy-pasted from text file into terminal to `touch` filename

Comment: The error message is clear: It claims about a missing `"/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf"`, not a missing `/Users/myusername/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf`. Your argument to cp starts with a `"`, which means that `cp` searches a subdirectory named `"`, and below it a directory named `Users`. You should have written `cp $A/$file $B/$file` ... no weird double-quote-acrobatic needed.

Comment: @user1934428 This is simply wrong. The quotes are required to protect an whitespace in the file names. What is not required is using `"\"$A\""` because this will put quotes into the actual argument passed to `cp`. Just try for yourself with some `echo` statements, or run `mkdir ~/.tmp; cd ~/.tmp; x="foo bar"; touch $x; ls -l` to see that the `touch` command creates two files.

Comment: @nohillside: Sorry, partially my bad: The correct cp command would be `cp $~A/$file $~B`. For debugging, you can easily see what's actually going on by turning on `set -x`. BTW, **no quotes needed**. You don't need quotes for protecting whitespaces: In zsh, parameter expansion occurs before word splitting.

Comment: @AussieCryptocurrency : nohillside suspected that you have CRs in your code. I don't think you do, but you can easily check this using, i.e., `xxd` or `od`, or any text editor which can show the code in hex.

Comment: @user1934428 Ah, zsh-specific you are correct of course. Still getting used to that :-)

Answer (score -1):

Oddly enough it did work when I tried to replicate it, even without doing much.

##### trythis.sh

```
rm -rf test1 test2 testme.txt
unset A
unset B

mkdir test1
mkdir test2

echo "the first file.pdf" > testme.txt
echo "the second file.pdf" >> testme.txt
echo "the third file.pdf" >> testme.txt

echo file1 > "test1/the first file.pdf"
echo file2 > "test1/the second file.pdf"
echo file3 > "test1/the third file.pdf"


A=test1
B=test2

tree

while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo cp "${A}/${file}" "${B}" ...
    cp "${A}/${file}" "${B}"
done < testme.txt
```

##### after `source trythis.sh`...

```
% tree
.
├── test1
│   ├── the\ first\ file.pdf
│   ├── the\ second\ file.pdf
│   └── the\ third\ file.pdf
├── test2
│   ├── the\ first\ file.pdf
│   ├── the\ second\ file.pdf
│   └── the\ third\ file.pdf
├── testme.txt
└── trythis.sh
```

```
% cat test2/the\ third\ file.pdf 
file3
```

---

Note:  I am not posting this to say the OP doesn't know what they're doing or doesn't have a problem.  Merely, since I had done this to check anyway, to provide a baseline of expected behavior.  Sometimes it's easier to work from known-working simple cases to debug something that is not working but is more complex.

Downvote away if you feel like it ;-)  It wasn't the OP anyway.

---

env:  zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0) / BigSur 11.6.5

Comment: I didn't downvote but you may get downvotes because the answer basically duplicates the shell script used in the question and just says "it works for me". This doesn't explain why it doesn't work for the OP though (and without them coming back to share details we'll probably never figure it out).

Comment: @nohillside Like I said, once I found it worked, I posted it up to provide a baseline to check from.  (without this explanatory footnote).  It doesn't duplicate the OP's setup however, because well, the OP doesn't work and we don't actually know what the OP has on their file system, or in their control file, when they run this.  I'll add version numbers for my zsh/macos though.

Comment: AskDifferent doesn't work like a typical forum site, answers are expected to actually answer the problem described in the question. You are right though, without knowing more details about the OP the question can't actually be answered.

Comment: @JLPeyret I have Mac Ventura, `zsh --version` `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`

Comment: @JLPeyret I don't have a command called `tree`.... `trythis.sh:20: command not found: tree`

Comment: tree doesnt do much you can skp it.  it only shows the nested file structure.  skip it and look around in the directories with ls and cd.  I am staring to think your problem could have been caused by leading / trailing extra spaces in your testme.txt.